# Private methods and fields

Tags: javascript

I'm evaluating [selfish](https://github.com/Gozala/selfish) and am wondering how I can declare private methods/fields?

Comment: Looking at the examples I'd say it's a pretty good question :))

Comment: I came up with this workaround here that involves private variables + closures, what do you think? http://marcelorjava.wordpress.com/2014/06/07/object-oriented-programming-with-java-and-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to do private functions is to use a function that your various "methods" close over, e.g. picking up their `Dog` example, change this:

```
// The basic Dog example
var Dog = Base.extend({
  bark: function() {
    return 'Ruff! Ruff!'
  }
});
```

To

```
// Adding a private function
var Dog = Base.extend((function(){
  function trulyPrivate() {
    console.log(this.bark());
  }

  return {
    bark: function() {
      return 'Ruff! Ruff!'
    },
    logBark: function() {
        trulyPrivate.call(this);
    }
  };
})());
```

Usage:

```
new Dog().logBark();  // logs "Ruff! Ruff!" using the truly private function behind the scenes
```

Re private *fields*, the usual way is to build anything that needs truly private fields from within your constructor function so they close over the (private) variables within the call to the constructor, a'la [Crockford's pattern](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html):

```
function Foo(arg) {
    var trulyPrivateData = arg;

    this.logIt = function() {
        console.log(trulyPrivateData);
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
var f = new Foo(42);
f.logIt(); // logs 42 even though there's no way, externally, to get that value from `f`
```

...selfish does away with the actual constructor function, but the `initialize` function should serve the same purpose:

```
var Dog = Base.extend({
  initialize: function(arg) {
    var woof = arg || 'Ruff! Ruff!';
    this.bark = function() {
        return woof;
    };
  }
});
```

Now, you can't set the `woof` (except at construction time, because we did that on purpose), you can only retrieve it from `bark`. E.g., it's truly private (other than that we've explicitly allowed `bark` to return it).

If you get into the technical details of this, these articles from my blog may (or may not) be useful, since when you get into private functions and such, you typically have to start managing `this`:

- [Mythical Methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [Private Methods in JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/private-methods-in-javascript.html) (seriously in need of an update/rewrite)

And if you want another thing to evaluate, there's my [`Lineage` project](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs), which is similarly pure prototypical inheritance, but with easy access to parent object properties, functions, etc. and a syntax that actively encourages private scopes for this sort of thing.

Comment: That gives you private properties at the class level; I'm not sure you could have per-instance private properties without some modifications to that framework. However I haven't had much coffee yet this morning.

Comment: @Pointy: There's no difference between "instance" and "class" level "methods" in JavaScript except how you call them. The way I called `trulyPrivate`, it was instance-specific. If I'd called it without `.call` and just passed in the `Dog` instance as an argument, it would have been "class"-specific. You can't do truly private functions that you call via `this.xyz()` notation directly in JavaScript (regardless of framework), because all properties on the instance are public. More (quite dated): http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/private-methods-in-javascript.html

Comment: Right right; I didn't see that there's an "initialize" nor really learn much else about that framework in the 15 seconds I spent on the github "readme" :-)  It's just making objects, so adding a property from a closure isn't any different with the framework than without it.